# TabPanel in a TabPanel

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, tabpanel

I have a main tabpanel to navigate through all the pages, and in one of these pages I have another tabpanel with 3 tabs. The problem is when I want to select the second tab from the controler.

This works perfectly for me, this code sends me to the other tabPanel in the main tab.

```
 this.viewPort.setActiveItem(
            this.viewPort.OperacionListForm, options.animation
);
```

and the problem is here, when I want to select the second tab

```
 var tab  = this.viewPort.OperacionListForm.addTab(ne);
 this.viewPort.OperacionListForm.setActiveItem(
            tab
        );
```

Comment: If you could provide more code we maybe able to help.  For example, what is the config of ne.